# How to display image from url in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an async call which the JSON response contains both text and url to images that I want to display in a UIImageView. Now displaying the text in a label isn't the problem but loading the images is giving me hard times. Have shared my code below.

```
//Declared variables to hold response
    var offerContent: String?
    var offerImage: URL?
    var offerTitle: String?
    var suggestionLabel:String?
    var suggestionScreen: String?



//create a task to send reques
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
                data, response, error in
                if error != nil {
                    print("error is:: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    return;
                }
                //parsing the response
                do {
                    // converting response to NSDictionary
                    let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let parseJSON = myJSON{
                            var responseCode: Int!
                            var responseMessage: NSArray!

                            //getting the json response
                            responseCode = parseJSON["RESPONSECODE"] as! Int?
                            responseMessage = parseJSON["RESPONSEMESSAGE"] as! NSArray?

                            if responseCode == 0 {
                                for obj in responseMessage{
                                    if let dict = obj as? NSDictionary{
                                        self.offerContent = dict.value(forKey: "CONTENT") as? String
                                        self.offerTitle = dict.value(forKey: "TITLE") as? String
                                        self.suggestionLabel = dict.value(forKey: "SUGGESTION_LABEL") as? String
                                        self.suggestionScreen = dict.value(forKey: "SUGGESTION_SCREEN") as? String
                                        self.offerImage = dict.value(forKey: "IMAGE") as? URL
//                                        print("image:: \(self.offerImage!)")

                                        let offerImageView = UIImageView()
                                        self.darkView.addSubview(offerImageView)
                                        offerImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
                                        offerImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.darkView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
                                        offerImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.darkView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
                                        offerImageView.image = UIImage(data: self.offerImage)
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            print(parseJSON)
                        }
                        }
                }catch{
                    print("catch:: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }

            }
            task.resume()
```

Comment: Is your `dict.value(forKey: "IMAGE")` content an url ?

Comment: you can use sdwebimage for displaying image url

Comment: @GIJOW yes it contains url. So i have edited my codes to make it url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loading/Downloading image from URL on Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift)

Comment: You can refer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24231680/loading-downloading-image-from-url-on-swift also, you're handling your url as data (binary data) `UIImage(data: self.offerImage)`. It will never work.

Comment: Thanks @MuhammedAzharudheen i imported sdwebimage and its working fine.

Answer (score 12):

Try this code.

```
let url = URL(string: "IMAGE URL HERE")
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)

if let imageData = data {
    let image = UIImage(data: imageData)
}
```

Comment: So simple! Thanks

Comment: What if I want to send some headers with the request?

Answer (score -1):

Import and use [Kingfisher](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher)

```
self.imageview.kf.setImage(with: "url")
```